# International call with twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio

Can I call Russian phone number with Twilio phone number?

client.calls.create({
    url: "http://31c35016.ngrok.io",
    to: "+79635160014",
    from: "+3238087418"
}

I have tried this code and I got errors.

{ [Error: Account not authorized to call +79635160014. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international]
  status: 400,
  message: 'Account not authorized to call +79635160014. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international',
  code: 21215,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21215',
  detail: undefined }

How can I handle this?
I thought about geo permission but there's no russian federation.

Answer (score 1):

this is the current place where you have to change your permissions https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/geo-permissions/low-risk

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You do need to update your [international permissions for voice calls](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions). If you filter, in the search bar at the top, for "Russia", you will see "Russia/Kazakhstan (+7)" under the Asia section.

Let me know if that helps at all.